# How do you structure your comparison functions?

Tags: c++, coding-style, language-features, lexicographic, stdtuple

I frequently encounter situations, especially with sorting in C++, where I am comparing a series of fields in order to compare a larger structure.  A simplified example:

```
struct Car{
    Manufacturer make;
    ModelName model;
    Year year;
};

bool carLessThanComparator( const Car & car1, const Car & car2 ){
    if( car1.make < car2.make ){
        return true;
    }else if( car1.make == car2.make ){
        if( car1.model < car2.model ){
            return true;
        }else if( car1.model == car2.model ){
            if( car1.year < car2.year ){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

My instinctive approach seems cumbersome, especially for more than 3 fields.  How would you structure this series of comparisons in C++?  Do other languages provide a more succinct or elegant syntax?

Comment: Personal style - I'd implement a `strcmp()` like function (or method) that returns 0 if a equals b, 1 if a is greater than b, and -1 if a is less than b, and then define the comparison operators (if you like) and/or methods in terms of the comparison function. Then we'd just have `bool carLessThanComparator( const Car & car1, const Car & car2 ) { return cmp(car1, car2) == -1; }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, if your function hits a return in the **if** clause, there's no need for an explicit **else**, since it would have already bailed out. That can save on the "indent valley":

```
bool carLessThanComparator( const Car & car1, const Car & car2 ) {
    if( car1.make < car2.make )
        return true;

    if ( car1.make != car2.make )
        return false;

    if( car1.model < car2.model )
        return true;

    if( car1.model != car2.model )
        return false;

    if( car1.year < car2.year )
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

I like MarkusQ's LISPish short-circuiting approach as well.

Comment: Why not just "return car1.year < car2.year" as the last statement?

Comment: Just for symmetry -- I wanted the code sample to be as clear as I could make it. In practice I'd do what you said, or really I'd code it like Markus did.

Answer (score 4):

If this happens a lot you could put a template like this into a common header:

```
template<typename T, typename A1, typename A2, typename A3>
bool
do_less_than(
        const typename T& t1,
        const typename T& t2,
        const typename A1 typename T::* a1,
        const typename A2 typename T::* a2,
        const typename A3 typename T::* a3)
{
    if ((t1.*a1) < (t2.*a1)) return true;
    if ((t1.*a1) != (t2.*a1)) return false;
    if ((t1.*a2) < (t2.*a2)) return true;
    if ((t1.*a2) != (t2.*a2)) return false;
    return (t1.*a3) < (t2.*a3);
}
```

Add other templates for different numbers of arguments as required.  For each less than function, you can then do something like this:

```
bool carLessThanComparator(const Car& car1, const Car& car2)
{
    return do_less_than(car1, car2, &Car::make, &Car::model, &Car::year);
}
```

Comment: I rarely see the pointer-to-member syntax in C++.  Very interesting.

Comment: And this is an example of why

Comment: The main point is that the complexity is in a library and is created once, while the common code becomes more simple.  The order of comparison in the actual comparison function is obvious and there are no inverted comparison bugs.

Answer (score 4):

Personally I'd suggest NOT using the != or == operators like we seem to recommend here - this requires the arguments/members to have both less then and equal operators just to do a less then check on a class containing them - using just the less then operator is enought and will save you redundancy and potential defects in the future.

I suggest you write:

```
bool operator<(const Car &car1, const Car &car2) 
{
    if(car1.make < car2.make)
        return true;
    if(car2.make < car1.make)
        return false;

    if(car1.model < car2.model)
        return true;
    if(car2.model < car1.model)
        return false;

    return car1.year < car2.year;
}
```

Comment: Good point.  This does allow you to implement the less-than comparison on the larger structure with only the requirement that less-than comparison is available for each member.

Answer (score 4):

I know it's an old question, but for future visitors: the modern C++11 solution is to use [**std::tie**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie)

```
struct Car{
    Manufacturer make;
    ModelName model;
    Year year;
};

bool operator<(Car const& lhs, Car const& rhs)
{
    return std::tie(lhs.make, lhs.model, lhs.year) < std::tie(rhs.make, rhs.model, rhs.year);
}
```

`std::tie` converts the struct into a `std::tuple` so that the above comparison operator delegates to `std::tuple::operator<`. This in turn does a lexicographical compare with respect to the order in which the members are marshalled into `std::tie`.

The lexicographic comparison is short-circuited in the same way as in the other solutions to this question. But it is even succinct enough to define on the fly inside a C++ lambda expression. For classes with private data members, it's best defined inside the class as `friend` function.

Answer (score 2):

```
bool carLessThanComparator( const Car & car1, const Car & car2 ){
    return (
      ( car1.make  < car2.make  ) or (( car1.make  == car2.make  ) and
      ( car1.model < car2.model ) or (( car1.model == car2.model ) and
      ( car1.year  < car2.year  ) 
      )));
```

-- MarkusQ

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd override the ==, <, >, and any other operators needed.  That would clean up the code, not in the comparison, but when you need to make the comparison.
For the actual comparison itself, I would write it similarly to what Crashworks said.

```
bool operator<(const Car &car1, const Car &car2) {
    if(car1.make < car2.make)
        return true;
    if(car1.make != car2.make)
        return false;
    if(car1.model < car2.model)
        return true;
    if(car1.model != car2.model)
        return false;
    return car1.year < car2.year;
}
```

Comment: Why not just "return car1.year < car2.year" as the last statement?  I agree with the operators thing, except I'd only do operator< and operator==, and then use something like boost::totally_ordered

Comment: I've never really looked at boost too much, but just looking up boost::totally_ordered, it would be useful.

As for the last statement... I actually just copied Crashwork's code when I saw it was the same style I'd use.  Using return like you said would be better.

Answer (score 2):

I was wondering the same thing as the OP and stumbled upon this question. After reading the answers I have been inspired by janm and RnR to write a `lexicographicalMemberCompare` template function that only uses only `operator<` on the compared members. It also uses [boost::tuple](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/tuple) so that you can specify as many members as you want. Here it is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>

template <class T, class Cons>
struct LessThan
{
    static bool compare(const T& lhs, const T& rhs, const Cons& cons)
    {
        typedef LessThan<T, typename Cons::tail_type> NextLessThan;
        typename Cons::head_type memberPtr = cons.get_head();
        return lhs.*memberPtr < rhs.*memberPtr ?
            true :
            (rhs.*memberPtr < lhs.*memberPtr  ?
                false :
                NextLessThan::compare(lhs, rhs, cons.get_tail()));
    }
};

template <class T>
struct LessThan<T, class boost::tuples::null_type>
{
    static bool compare(const T& lhs, const T& rhs,
                        const boost::tuples::null_type& cons)
    {
        return false;
    }
};

template <class T, class Tuple>
bool lexicographicalMemberCompare(const T& lhs, const T& rhs,
                                  const Tuple& tuple)
{
    return LessThan<T, typename Tuple::inherited>::compare(lhs, rhs, tuple);
}

struct Car
{
    std::string make;
    std::string model;
    int year;
};

bool carLessThanCompare(const Car& lhs, const Car& rhs)
{
    return lexicographicalMemberCompare(lhs, rhs,
        boost::tuples::make_tuple(&Car::make, &Car::model, &Car::year));
}

int main()
{
    Car car1 = {"Ford", "F150", 2009};
    Car car2 = {"Ford", "Escort", 2009};
    std::cout << carLessThanCompare(car1, car2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << carLessThanCompare(car2, car1) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this is useful to someone.

Comment: You have an `operator>`. Also, comparison functions tend to be written outside the class. Otherwise pretty nifty.

Comment: Oops. Fixed `operator>` and put `operator<` outside class. I didn't receive the memo about why putting comparison operators inside classes is bad (when the lhs is already the class itself).

Comment: Even if it's just `operator<` or something, it's still generally better to keep it outside the class, for consistency.

Comment: Oof, what was I smoking? This can be done in a single line now in C++11 with std::tie. See TemplateRex's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15723660/245265